# Wireless display in Windows - how to use the actual mouse cursor

Tags: windows-10, miracast

When connecting to a Samsung TV using Windows "Connect to a wireless display" (when you hit WinKey+P), the mouse cursor is rendered independently by the TV and is always an arrow rather than using the one that is currently being used by the operating system which may be a text or graphics editing one.  This makes it hard to use productivity applications.

Is there any way to customize this?  I understand the intent is to optimize how much data is sent over the wireless connection, but assuming that is not an issue or the tradeoff is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the size of the cursor at least to "3". Then all changes of currsor will apply also on Samsung TV.

Comment: How to do that?